# Prove that $3(\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}) \ge 10 + 8\cdot \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> For the positive real numbers $a, b, c$ prove that $$3\bigg(\dfrac{a+b}{c}+\dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}\bigg) \ge 10 + 8\cdot \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}$$

I did the following:
$$\begin{split}\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca} & = \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)}{ab+bc+ca} \\ & = \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca} - 2 \\ & \le \dfrac{a}{b} + \dfrac{b}{c} + \dfrac{c}{a} -2\end{split}$$

I got the last one by applying Titu's Lemma

Thus I think it suffices to prove that $$3\bigg(\dfrac{a+b}{c}+\dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}\bigg) \ge 10 + 8\bigg(\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}-2\bigg) \\ \Longrightarrow 3a^2b+3b^2c+3c^2a+6abc \ge 5a^2c+5b^2a+5c^2b$$

But by rearrangement inequality this is not always true I think. The direction of the inequality should have been flipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we must prove that $$3\bigg(\dfrac{a+b}{c}+\dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}\bigg) \ge 10 + 8\bigg(\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}\bigg) \\ $$
Adding $6$ gives us 
$$\dfrac{3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{abc} \ge \dfrac{8(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca}$$
However, since $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \ge \dfrac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$, it is enough to prove that $(ab+bc+ca)^2 \ge 3abc(a+b+c)$, which follows from $(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3ab+3bc+3ca$. Our proof is done.

Comment: where does $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \ge \dfrac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$ come from?

Comment: Simplifying both sides gives $\sum _{ sym }^{  }{ a^2b }\ge6abc$, which can be proved with AM-GM.

Comment: $\frac{3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{abc} \ge \frac{8(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca} \Rightarrow 9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \ge 8(a+b+c)^2\frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}$ is it wise here to use in the RHS the GM-HM or AM-HM inequality?

Comment: @user302454 What exactly do you mean by that? I do  not think that using GM-HM or AM-HM would prove very effective.

Comment: @user302454  Also, is there a problem with /something you did not understand with my proof?

Comment: Nope! your proof is perfect! I just thought using AM-GM-HM might be easier

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, your inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$.

Hence, it remains to prove it for an extremal value of $w^3$, which happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$. In this case our inequality is obvious;
2. $b=c=1$, which gives $(a-1)^2(2a+3)\geq0$. Done!